# What is the difference between gcloud app deploy and kubectl expose deployment?

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm testing google cloud. I'm following official tutorials.

I wanted to start with simple node.js app. I've learnt how to setup a basic dockers cluster: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app

I also tried simply using `gcloud app deploy`. I thought it's like a shortcut for the above.

I noticed few things:

- Both can run separately and be accessed from internet.
- `gcloud app deploy` creates a new app version under `App Engine > Versions`.
  Moreover, seems like all of them are live I can migrate traffic
  between them. I don't see anything similar while exposing
  dockerimage.
- `gcloud app deploy` creates a downtime!
- `gcloud app deploy` app isn't listed while executing `kubectl get pods`

Can someone explain me the differences between those methods and what should I do not to waste resources.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about 2 **different** [GCP products](https://cloud.google.com/products/):

- the documentation you referenced and the `kubectl` CLI apply to [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/)
- the [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) applies to [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/)

Comment: I understand that. I'm curious what actions does appengine actually do and how do they overlap with kubernates pipeline

Comment: They're totally non-overlapping.